# Node.js and File System on Windows - EBUSY error

Tags: windows, node.js, filesystems

I'm new to Node.js and I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with the following code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = "C:\\";
var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var name = fs.statSync(dir + files[i]).name;
}
```

When running this code I get the error:

```
Error: EBUSY, resource busy or locked 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
    at Object.statSync (fs.js:424:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (S:\start.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Comment: Try this first 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566236/npm-install-error-code-ebusy-errono-4082/45757541#45757541

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hiberfil.sys is a system file that holds the hibernation data onto disk, you cannot just read it via normal rights, it's super confidential since it hold all memory information on disk.

Comment: Just tossing a note in here for reference:
Using a try/catch fixed my problem with this error message. `try { var name = fs.statSync(path); }` -- it just ignores it if the file cannot be read for whatever reason, and moves on. Node has really helped me understand the value of error handling in JS.

Comment: @Adrian can you pls make a full example of you solution thanks in advance

Comment: @haltman I posted this more than five years ago. I don't remember the context for my comment nor the discovery that led to it, plus I have not used JavaScript or Node very much in the past two years. I think my point was that using try/catch when trying to read a directory helped avoid pointless errors like trying to read a protected system file. Wrap the fs.statSync call in a try block, and catch any errors it throws rather than allowing them to crash your app

Answer (score 1):

After having a similar issue without finding a sufficient answer:

I have fixed it by searching for circular dependencies.

After fixing it, I was able to run everything normally.
[image]